# i'm using the same filter method on 2 different arrays with the same amount of elements but im getting back 2 different values

Tags: javascript

```
let initialArtists = [
    { id: 0, name: 'Marta Colvin Andrade' },
    { id: 1, name: 'Lamidi Olonade Fakeye'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Louise Nevelson'},
  ];

  let artist = initialArtists.filter(a => a.id);
  
  console.log(artist);
```

```
let users = [
    {id: 1, name: "John"},
    {id: 2, name: "Pete"},
    {id: 3, name: "Mary"}
  ];
  
  let someUsers = users.filter(item => item.id);

  console.log(someUsers);
```

Using the filter method for both arrays, I'm getting unexpected returns for the first artist array .

The first array is returning only 2 elements of the array and the second array is returning all 3.

Comment: Your filter is basically doing “return each element that has a non-zero id”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code executes properly, since your first inital artist has id = 0, then it filtered  out since filter includes only `truthy` filter values, so only the rest 2 artists are in the filtered array. It's not clear why you filter it.
Maybe you wanted to get list of user IDs? In that case you need `Array::map()`:

```js
let initialArtists = [
    { id: 0, name: 'Marta Colvin Andrade' },
    { id: 1, name: 'Lamidi Olonade Fakeye'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Louise Nevelson'},
  ];

  let artist = initialArtists.map(a => a.id);
  
  console.log(artist);
```